# Resizing an already shown ViewController

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I am not sure if what I want is possible or not but here is the scenario:

```
MainViewController 
                |
                 ------ ChildViewController (White)
                                         |
                                          ------ SecondChildViewController (Red)
```

`SecondChildViewController` has three states: 1) Presented 2) Minimized 3) Dismissed

What I want is achieving **Preview** state which is basically moving the presented view (red one) downward after tapping, say, `Preview` button while it's still presented.

*What I want is not resizing a UIView, it's about resizing a presented view controller.*

[image]

Comment: This happens when your constraints are missing, please check your constraints.

Comment: This is a whole ViewController, not a UIView within another ViewController. I explained the hierarchy in the question.